# AVFoundation: Get CMSampleBuffer from Preview View (while recording at the same time)

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, avfoundation

I'm trying to create a camera capture session that has the following features:

1. Preview
2. Photo capture
3. Video capture
4. Realtime frame processing (AI)

While the first two things are not a problem, I haven't found a way to make the last two separately.

Currently, I use a single `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and run the video recording first, then the frame processing in the same function, in the same queue. (see code [here](https://github.com/cuvent/react-native-vision-camera/blob/49ae9844da0daf8ce259c2b2f482e1baed4a82c8/ios/CameraView%2BAVCaptureSession.swift#L16-L134) and [here](https://github.com/cuvent/react-native-vision-camera/blob/49ae9844da0daf8ce259c2b2f482e1baed4a82c8/ios/CameraView%2BRecordVideo.swift#L121-L146))

The only problem with this is that the video capture captures 4k video, and I don't really want the frame processor to receive 4k buffers as that is going to be very slow and blocks the video recording (frame drops).

Ideally I want to create one `AVCaptureDataOutput` for 4k video recording, and another one that receives frames in a lower (preview?) resolution - but you cannot use two `AVCaptureDataOutput`s in the same capture session.

I thought maybe I could "hook into" the Preview layer to receive the `CMSampleBuffer`s from there, just like the `captureOutput(...)` func, since those are in preview-sized resolutions, does anyone know if that is somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

For such thing I recommended implement custom renderer flow.
You need just one AVCaptureDataOutput without system PreviewLayer which provided by iOS.

- Setup Color scheme to YUV (it's more compact then BGRA)
- Get CMSampleBuffer in AVCaptureDataOutput
- Send CMSampleBuffer to Metal texture.
- Create resized low resolution texture in Metal
- Hi resolution texture send to Renderer in draw it in MTKLView
- Low resolution texture send to CVPixelBuffer, then you can convert it to CGImage, CGImage, Data.
- Send low resolution image to Neural network

I have article on Medium: [link](https://dmytrohrebeniuk.medium.com/using-metal-performance-shaders-for-realtime-fast-style-transfer-90c2303302c9). You can use it as some example.

Comment: That's a clever idea, but compared to how the PreviewLayer works right now, there is an additional latency introduced (by resizing the buffer, etc) - and I think I won't be able to run 60, 120, or even 240, FPS video recordings, don't you think?

Comment: PreviewLayer works right, but if you wanna custom processing should application should 2 times preprocessing image from camera to GPU.

Approach fix custom rendered it's difficult and expensive way, but it's give to you much more ways for smart optimizations.